# What is $\Bbb Q_p(p^{1/p^\infty})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

What is $\Bbb Q_p(p^{1/p^\infty})$ ? I am mainly looking for a reference - i.e. which topic of number theory does this fall into?

I know what $\Bbb Q_p$ is but i don't understand the notation $p^{1/p^\infty}$ means.

Context: I am trying to understand this [post.](https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2017/02/20/the-fontaine-winterberger-theorem-going-full-tilt/)

Comment: $\bigcup_n \Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^n})$

Comment: It is the field obtained by adjoining all $p$-power roots of $p$, a totally wildly ramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: (and then completing $p$-adically).

Comment: I guess its usefulness comes from that $T_K=\bigcup_{p\ \nmid\ n} K(\zeta_n,p^{1/n})$ is the largest tamely ramified extension of $K$, with $F=\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^{\infty}})$ then $T_F$ is dense in $\Bbb{C}_p$ (really ?) thus $Gal(T_F/F) = Gal( \overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p/F)$

Comment: I learn from other people that $T_F$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}_p$, and sketch the proof as follows. Take $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p \smallsetminus T_F$ defined by the equation $\alpha^p+\alpha + \frac{1}{p}=0$. By the Krasner's lemma,
$$|\alpha-\beta| \geqslant \operatorname*{min}_{\substack{\sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}\left(T_F(\alpha)/T_F\right)\\ \sigma \neq Id}} |\alpha-\sigma(\alpha)|$$
for any $\beta \in T_F$, thus $\alpha$ can not be approximated by any sequences in $T_F$.

Comment: When the Krasner's lemma is applied, the base field is any NA local field containing $\beta$ (rather than $T_F$), to satisfy the condition of completeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition would be $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^{\infty}}) = \bigcup \mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/p^{n}})$, which means you adjoin all $p$-power roots of $p$. This arises in the study of (wildly) ramified extensions if you want to read about it and it is very natural to study ramification in number theory.

Comment: Is there any recommended text/notes/papers about this?

Comment: You can read about ramification theory in *Corps Locaux* of Serre, translated as *Local Fields*.